# How to handle headers in apache camel

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-camel

If i have a InOut route like,

```
    from("activemq:queue:MY_QUEUE")
        .process(this.processor1)
        .to("ahc:http:\\abc.com/v1/post/id=123")
        .process(this.processor2);
```

How can i ensure that only specific HTTP headers (e.g., Accept, Authorization, Content-Type) are passed to ahc component whereas JMS header (JMSReplyTo) are propagated until end of the route ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you process exchange in your processor1 just set all required headers/body not to "exchange.getIn()..." but to the "exchange.getOut().."

More details can be found in the documentation
http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: how do i propagate a header field(or some data) from processor1 to processor2 ?

Comment: The exchange.out from processor 1 is the exchange,in in next processor. So set header on out in processor 1. Also i believe, headers are passed till the end of the route unless you explicitly remove them.If you need to send data between processors, you can also set a property on exchange as well.

Comment: In general exchange headers are not for custom data exchange (even if we can use them in that way) but mostly for protocol-related params like http method/uri/sftp-path etc.

For transferring own data between different route parts (including processors) you need to use exchange properties. They are related to exchange in general (not to in or out message) and stay until you will not remove them. Almost all (if not all) route processors like split/loop/multicast are preserving them